# Hyper-V Replication Failures

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have 2 sites with failover clusters running Hyper-V 2012.  When I started this job the production website (site A) was on Server 2008 running Coldfusion 9, SQL 2008 all on one machine.  I upgraded to Server 2012 running ColdFusion 11 and am using the 2008 box as the database for the site.

Site B was upgraded as well to mirror Site A.

Replication has not worked since the upgrade.  Now it is calling for a resynchronization.  I scheduled the sync to run after hours last night and it failed.

> "Cannot initiate resynchronization because initial replication for the virtual machine 'production db' is pending completion."

It seems to me that this is not going to work.

My question is, would it be more time efficient to remove the replication and start it all over?  I know I am not well versed in this area, but I have done some digging on this and haven't been successful in finding answers.  I would like to hear from someone who deals with virtuals and replications, some valid sound advice would be Wonderful! 
I appreciate and thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: How did you set up the original two sites? Did you use replication to start the second site or... ? I know that you're asking about failover, but it sounds more like you're set up for high availability. What is the purpose of having Site A and Site B? Is Site B for failing over to if Site A goes down or are Site A and Site B both up at the same time sharing the load?

Comment: I didn't set up the original sites, the previous admin did and there are no notes or documentation.  Yes, it is set up for high availability.  Site B is supposed to failover if Site A fails.

Comment: So, Site B goes unused until Site A fails? If this is the case, then yes, it'll probably be easier to redo Site B so that it's replicating Site A correctly, and so that you can then properly document the setup.

Comment: @austinian When you say redo Site B, you are only referring to the replication right?  I thought I had to initiate replication from the main site, in this instance Site A.  I have never worked with Hyper-V before so this is all new to me.  I thought I was doing pretty well getting it all upgraded and running.  But without the replication working I know I am a sitting duck.

Comment: On Site B, you have to set up the server as a replica server. After it's set up as a replica server, then you can tell Site A to use Site B as a replication target. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/yungchou/archive/2013/01/10/hyper-v-replica-explained.aspx, it's a good article on the subject, and deals specifically with 2012.

Comment: And yes, as long as Hyper-V is set up and behaving normally at both sites, I'd just redo the replication.

Comment: The operating system and applications running on your virtual machines is immaterial to Hyper-V Replica so stop thinking about that aspect. My suggestion would be to disable Hyper-V Replica and start from scratch.